# What is the rationale behind applying IStartup filter in reverse order

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

In Asp.net core, all middleware is applied in the order in which it was configured. However, IStartupFilters are applied in the reverse order of definition as can be seen here [lines 92-95 in this](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/cfe9b26a34af15c4943240d790ee5d1a168290c9/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/GenericHost/GenericWebHostedService.cs).
Even if IStartupFilters are applied at the start of the application, why would the order need to be reversed?

Example of order of filters in which they were registered indicating that due to reversal, asp.net core startup filters will run last.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The rationale was discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/653#issuecomment-197927053).

Essentially, it is to ensure that `IStartupFilter`s run in a "register first, run first" order, which is consistent with the execution order of middlewares. Besides this nice benefit of consistency, it also ensured that the default framework-registered `IStartupFilter`s get run before user-registered ones (this point is no longer valid though, as default `IStartupFilter`s have all been removed as of version 3.0).

Comment: Really appreciate your comment here but I am unable to see how reverse is helping with FIFO. I edited the question to include a screenshot in which because of reversal, .net core filters will run after the user registered ones